# Children's story: Boy travels with knight to the castle

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, audio-book

When I was a child in the 90's, we had some cassette tapes with some stories. This one was about a boy who rides with a knight to the castle, with the hope to become a knight. Things I remember from the story:

1. Had sound effects like the horse hooves, crickets chirping, etc.
2. The boy gets separated from the knight, left in a town. Eventually he gets pulled into a crowd that is running around all these stalls, buying things. One stall has many different watches of different colors. Another stall has ice cream. Eventually he is so exhausted as night is falling and he gets away from the crowd. Then he maybe finds the knight at an inn?
3. Later he gets separated from the knight and has to choose a path at a fork in the road. A magical fairy sends a bunny running across one trail to try to signal to the boy which way to go.
4. The story ends with the boy and knight arriving at the castle.